# lucene index lookup query slower than where clause based query for more data

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am facing issues where lucene index lookup in start clause is slower than where clause.
e.g

i am running neo4j 1.9.M05 on a mac with java process having 4 gb of  heap with 1.5 milllion nodes and 5 million relationships and 5 million properties.

The query looks like below....basically it has match and other where conditions. We were trying to optimize lot of queries by index lookup, so changing the existing query which does not have index lookup, but looks like index lookup is slower

```
CYPHER 1.8 START a=node(21102),
cu=node:myindex(id="020513_1359970281348_1360024480338_2") 
MATCH cu<-[:cp_in]-(cp),
(out)<-[:ap]-(cp),
(out)-[:ac]->(path0_child)-[:acp*0..10]->(path0)
,(out)<-[:ahp]-(a) 
WHERE path0.id! =~'(?i)^\\Qtest\\E$' 
RETURN DISTINCT out SKIP 0 LIMIT 50
```

we are using spring data and putting the index lookup cache does not seem to help

```
Index<Node> index = template.getGraphDatabase().getIndex("myindex");
((LuceneIndex<Node>) index).setCacheCapacity("id", 30000000);
```

Any clue or advice much appreciated

Regards

Sai